# Query across several schemes in a single database in SQl Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server database that has several schemes all with same tables storing client-specific data. To be specific, it's like:

```
[database1].[client1].[table1]
[database1].[client2].[table1]
[database1].[client3].[table1]
```

And so on.
Each schema has several different tables though I want to access only to one same table but change Client schemes dynamically.
The main goal is to find, say, total sales for each client. Hope it makes sense.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use dynamic sql to achieve this...

Comment: Using multiple schemas like this is not a good way to implement multi-tenancy. Is there a reason this design was chosen?

Comment: I suspect you'll need to use dynamic SQL: it can't SELECT FROM <variable>.

Comment: @Dai, unfortunately, I cannot answer your question since I am more of a DB user for now rather one who's is in charge of its architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below script. it selects all the columns for all rows in your table. You can also add your custom columns and where conditions in the query string :

```
DECLARE @Clients AS TABLE
(
    SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ClientName VARCHAR(255),
    Qry VARCHAR(MAX)
)
DECLARE @v_Min INT,@v_Max INT,@TempQry VARCHAR(MAX)

INSERT INTO @Clients
(
    ClientName,
    Qry
)
SELECT
    DISTINCT 
        TABLE_SCHEMA,
        Qry = 'SELECT * FROM [DatabaseName].['+TABLE_SCHEMA+'].['+TABLE_NAME+']'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('Your Table Name')

SELECT
    @v_Min = MIN(SeqNo),
    @v_Max = MAX(SeqNo)
    FROM @Clients

WHILE ISNULL(@v_Min,0) <= ISNULL(@v_Max,0)
BEGIN

    SELECT
        @TempQry = Qry
        FROM @Clients
            WHERE SeqNo = @v_Min

    EXEC(@TempQry)

    SELECT
        @v_Min = ISNULL(@v_Min,0)+1

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'Database 1' as Name, sum([db1].[dbo].table1.sales) as Total_Sales from [db1].[dbo].table1
union
select 'Database 2' as Name, sum([db2].[dbo].table1.sales) as Total_Sales from [db2].[dbo].table1
```

is the most trivial example. If you have many clients, then it might be feasible to have a database where you store what clients you have. In that database the client database paths could be stored in a `table` like this:

**Clients(ID, Name, DBPath, TotalSales)**

Then you could create a stored procedure which would update Clients.TotalSales, using a stored function which would receive a DBPath and return its TotalSales.

Answer (score 0):

What about one SQL statement,

```
Select (Select **ifnull**(**sum**(**Total**),0) FROM **Schema1**.**sale**) + (Select **ifnull**(**sum**(**Total**),0) FROM **Schema2**.**sale**) + (Select **ifnull**(**sum**(**Total**),0) FROM **Schema3**.**sale**) + .....
```

But You would have to know all schemas names.

I supposed that '**Total**' is the name of the field/column which you want to get total. 
And '**Sale**' is the name of the **Table**.